# In PowerShell Encode text for Email to display Unicode characters properly

Tags: email, powershell, unicode, utf-8

I have this string:

```
You owe me a total of ₦7,500.00
```

Now I need to include the text in the body of an email. How can I encode this in UTF8 to have the currency symbol display properly in the user agent?

```
'''
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($From, $To)
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$message.Body = $contentText
$message.BodyEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
'''
```

For whatever reason, this does not seem to work. What I get is still this:

```
You owe me a total of â‚¦7,500.00
```

When I use `Get-Content` to draw the text from a file like so:

```
$message.Body = (gc C:/temp/email.txt -Encoding UTF8)
```

It works, as the email displays correctly. However, I need to be able to do the encoding with the string, since the source of my email body is not a file.

Comment: I had a similar issue when using an API. Try this: `$message.Body = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($contentText)`

Comment: Flagrant mojibake case: bytes `0xE2 0x82 0xA6` (i.e. `UTF-8` representation of `₦` _Naira Sign_) are  interpreted as characters of code page 1252. In other (powershell) words, `â‚¦` is output from `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString(
    [system.text.encoding]::Convert(
        [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1200),
        [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(65001),
 [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1200).GetBytes("₦")))`.

Comment: Thanks @David for your kind suggestion. Unfortunately when I tried that, the entire mail body looks like this: `60 100 105 118 32 105 100 61 34 109 97 105 108 104 101 97 100 101 114 119 114 97 112 34 32 115 116 121 108 101 61 34 109 97 114 103 105 110 45 98 111 116 116 111 109 58 49 101 109 59 32 112 97 100 100 105 110 103 45 98 111 116 116 111 109 58 49 101 109 59 32 98 111 114 100 101 114 45 98 111 116 116 111 109 58 32 49 112 120 32 115 111 108 105 100 32 35 50 50 98 49 52 99 59 34 62 32 32 9 60 105 109 103 32 115 114 99 61 34 99 105 100 58 108 111 103 111 46 112 110 103 34 32 115 ....`

Comment: @JosefZ I appreciate your input. At the end of the day, though, I'm looking for an answer: How do I get this to work?

Comment: I can see that `$contentText` is a complex string `<div id="mailheaderwrap" style=…`. Is `$contentText` displayed properly on your monitor? Would the mojibake case come even with the simplest `$contentText="₦"`? Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]  how `$contentText` is computed.